# Ошибка при компиляции связаная с сериализацией

Tags: golang, docker, build

Учусь заворачивать проект в docker-контейнер. Когда я выполняю `go build .` в корне проекта (без сборки), то все собирается в бинарник нормально, а когда выполняю там же `docker build .` то выскакивает такое:

```
Step 6/13 : RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app .
 ---> Running in af2d1c89685c
# github.com/gin-gonic/gin/binding
go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/binding/json.go:50:10: decoder.DisallowUnknownFields undefined (type *"encoding/json".Decoder has no field or method DisallowUnknownFields)
The command '/bin/sh -c CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app .' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Подскажите в чем дело. В учебном проекте есть работа с MongoDB и сериализация различная.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этот метод появился в *Go* **1.10**.  Значит, у вас в контейнере
более старая версия.  Проверить это можно с помощью команды:

```sh
$ go version
```

Comment: Да, действительно, у меня в докерфайле стояла версия 1.9. Скопировал со статьи одной и не посмотрел, спасибо большое!